# Python - Can I use lru_cache on a function that returns a dictionary

Tags: python

Can I use `lru_cache` to improve performance of a function that returns a dictionary?

Based on the below statement, it seems like `lru_cache` shouldnt be used on mutable collections(dict, list, set). But I don't want to read values from config file and populate the dictionary everytime the function is invoked. Instead if it's in the cache, I just want to return the cached value. Added my code snippet below. Should I use lru_cache for my usecase to improve performance?

> In general, the LRU cache should only be used when you want to reuse previously computed values. Accordingly, it doesn’t make sense to cache functions with side-effects, functions that need to create distinct mutable objects on each call, or impure functions such as time() or random().
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def func():
    config_dict = dict()
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')   
    for section in config.sections():
        for key in config.options(section):
           config_dict[key] = value
    return config_dict
```

Comment: Do the contents in `config.ini` change over time? If so, why do you want to use caching? If not, why do you want to wrap the reading of the config file in a function?

Comment: The problem with caching a mutable object is that you can pollute the cache by mutating the object.  In your example, the caller of `func()` might modify the cached `config_dict`, which would then affect it for every other caller of `func()`.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark - seems like a reasonable thing to do. First reader causes the config to be parsed, future readers do not.

Comment: I think the key here is "distict" You just keep grabbing the same config over and over, so caching is fine. Mostly. A piece of code that modifies the config would be problematic. But then that's always the risk, even if the config is just a global variable.